# Array#prepend/append undefined in Rails 3.1.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Going through the [Active Support Core Extensions guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html), it looks like some of them are not available. Here's verbatim output from a new session:

```
$ rails --version
Rails 3.1.3
$ rails console
[1] pry(main)> [].prepend(10)
NoMethodError: undefined method `prepend' for []:Array
from (pry):1:in `<main>'
[2] pry(main)> [].unshift(10)
=> [10]
[3] pry(main)> %w(a b c d).append('e')
NoMethodError: undefined method `append' for ["a", "b", "c", "d"]:Array
from (pry):3:in `<main>'
[4] pry(main)> %w(a b c d) << 'e'
=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
[5] pry(main)> require 'active_support/core_ext/array'
=> false
```

There's nothing indicating that `append` and `prepend` are deprecated or cutting-edge only, so what is happening here?

Looks like these are actually not part of Rails 3.1.3, because these fail:

```
$ grep 'prepend\|append' ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@project_name/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/*
$ ls ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@taclom/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/prepend_and_append.rb
```

Comment: I am using rails 3.0.7, I am also getting same error. Well we can use `push` for appending and `unshift` for prepending.

Comment: I can't actually find the file the guide references in the history of Rails. What version of Rails can you see this in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These methods [were added](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9482554f31f3ac7f941e6239890c60fcc01975e1#activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/prepend_and_append.rb) in `3.2.0` and are nothing more than aliases to `<<` and `unshift` respectively.

Comment: I can't find an *online API reference* for v3.1.3. api.rubyonrails.org doesn't seem to have a link to it. Is there any?

Comment: Nevermind, finally found the correct [v3.1.3 API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.1.3/) link.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's only available from [Rails v3.2.1](http://api.rubyonrails.org/files/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/prepend_and_append_rb.html).

Comment: they have been added in august, but they are not present in any 3.1 gem source. https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9482554f31f3ac7f941e6239890c60fcc01975e1#activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/array.rb

Comment: I believe they were added to the `master` branch that later became `v3.2.0`, but were not backported to `3-1-stable` branch.